# Tables not visible inside Database after Query Execution

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I tried to create a new Database and some Tables and executed Query successfully, but my tables are not visible in Object Explorer, but my Database is created. Refreshed the Object Explorer as well!

Could you please help me sort this out?

```
    Create DATABASE CustomerOrders
    GO

    USE CustomerOrders;
    GO

   CREATE TABLE dbo.Customerdetails
    (
    Customer_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PhoneNumber int NOT NULL,
    Address nvarchar(100)
    );
    GO

    INSERT dbo.Customerdetails
    VALUES ('ABC', +91-123456789, 'SF'), ('DEF', +1-123432145, 'California');
    GO


    CREATE TABLE dbo.Productdetails
    (
    Product_ID int IDENTITY(2015160,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Product_Name nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    UnitPrice money NOT NULL,
    ISSN_No varchar(100) NOT NULL
    );
    GO


    INSERT dbo.Productdetails
    VALUES ('QWERR', 15000, 'ASD123//456'), ('ERRT', 45000, 'APP4352223//234');
    GO


    CREATE TABLE dbo.Orderdetails
    (
    Order_ID int IDENTITY(00001,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Cust_ID int NOT NULL,
    Prod_ID int NOT NULL,
    Quantity int NOT NULL,
    ProductName nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Customer_ID FOREIGN KEY (Cust_ID)
    REFERENCES CustomerDetails(Customer_ID), 
    CONSTRAINT FK_Product_ID FOREIGN KEY (Prod_ID)
    REFERENCES ProductDetails(Product_ID) 
    );
    GO

    INSERT dbo.Productdetails
    VALUES ('Sony_Xperia', 5, 'SWER2525//35'), ('Apple-I series', 2, 'SWER2525//35');
    GO
```

Comment: Refresh your database inside object explorer.

Comment: Ya, but that not helped me

Comment: Are your tables shown when you run `SELECT * FROM sys.tables` in your new database

Comment: No. I executed the above statement as well but could not get the tables

Comment: Try Running only the table creation script again (starting from `USE CustomerOrders;`). It works properly on my end.

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM dbo.Productdetails` return results or an error?

Answer (score 0):

i tried out in my machine.but its working fine.its shows all tables in object explorer.

**Just disconnect server and connect again and check it out.**